# How can I add users in a private room with a command when they are mentioned?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a command and in this command when I run it, it has to create a room and add the people mentioned. Instead, it adds the user who used the command. How can I fix my code?

```py
@client.command()
async def real1v1(ctx, member: discord.Member, arg, product, *, stars):
  embed = discord.Embed(title = f "New realistic 1v1 wager for {arg}", description = f "** Team 1: {product} vs Team 2: {stars} **", color = discord.Color.red())
  guild = ctx.guild
  member = ctx.author
  member2 = ctx.author.member
  admin_role = get(guild.roles, name = "RoleTestAdmin")
  overwrites = {
        guild.default_role:discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = False),
        member:discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True),
        member2:discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True),
        admin_role:discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True)
    }
  channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f'Team1-Team2 ', overwrites = overwrites)
  #await channel.send(f"{product} {stars}")
  embed.set_footer(text = f"{ctx.guild.name}")
  await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`discord.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=greedy#discord.ext.commands.Greedy). For example:

```py
async def real1v1(ctx, target_members: discord.Greedy[discord.Member]):
    # `target_members` is a list of members
    # do stuff
    #await ctx.send(f'member 0 of {len(members)} is {members[0].display_name}')
```

This can be invoked like `real1v1 @member name#1111 @anothermember` and you'll get a list of the members.

For your overwrites, you can add the new members like this:

```py
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = False),
    member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True),
    member2: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True),
    admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True)
}
overwrites.update({member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True) for member in target_members})
```